# UIWebView blocking popups-also blocks the original site

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to block popups, but i see that the url that the delegate method reads is different from the original url : original :  `http://ti.me/1ifSRHg` where i see : `ti.me`

//block popups

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *host = [request.URL host];
    NSLog(@"host:%@",host); // host:ti.me
    if ( [host isEqualToString:[Globals sharedGlobals].currentLink] )
    {
        NSLog(@"yes");

        return YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"no");
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh ok , i look for the host ,

it should be

```
NSURL *host = request.URL;
```